# Prove that open cubes are open sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

I want to prove that any open "cube" is open.
Given a metric space $M$, in particular $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $I_i$ ($i=1,..., n$) open intervals, we define cube by
$$C(x; \delta)= I_1 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times I_n=]a_{1} - \delta, a_{1} + \delta [ \times ... \times ] a_{n} - \delta, a_{n} + \delta [$$
We must then prove that for all $x\in B(a;r)$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $C(x; \delta)\subset B(a;r)$.

In my attempt to prove the above, what I did was to take $x\in B(a;r)$ such that $d(x,a)<r$, thus I can state that $\delta=r-d(x,a)$.
By working a bit with the triangular inequality one can get to prove the contention. However, a doubt arises. When proving that an open ball is an open set one takes $d(x,a)=||x-a||$ and in a certain way the inequalities fit, however when it is a cube, what changes?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So much messiness in this question. Why mention $M,$ rather than just start with $\mathbb R^n?$ Why use $\delta$ for the interval radiuses when you are going to want a different $\delta$ later? This kind of problem is pretty easy if you get the notation right. It is worth trying to first prove $(0,1)^n$ is open in $\mathbb R^n.$ All ofther cubes follow by scaling and translating the argument from there.

Comment: It is even worse than not getting the notation right. @Wrloord : If you want to prove that the cube $C(x;\delta)$ is open it it nonsense to prove that for each $x$ in the ball $B(a;r)$ there exists a cube around $x$ contained in the ball .